# What is the difference between "turn off" and "shut down" in Windows 7 version of Virtual PC?

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v, virtual-machines

In Virtual PC (on Windows 7) what is the difference between choosing Shut Down vs. Turn Off?

Comment: Also applies to Hyper-V.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449415(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*turn off* is like physically pulling the plug, it's a hard power off.

*shutdown* is like pressing the soft switch on most modern PC's which will initiate an OS system shutdown.

Comment: Shutdown [...] or selecting shutdown within the OS.